Issues with Flink CDC for SQL Server to SQL Server Data Synchronization
Description:

Background: I am new to Flink and have no prior experience with big data. My knowledge of Java or Linux is also limited.

Requirement: I want to use Flink CDC to perform a simple data table synchronization test between SQL Server databases, Specifically, using yaml files instead of java code

Environment Information:





name
version




flink
flink-1.19.1


Flink CDC
flink-cdc-3.1.0


SQL Server
SQL Server 2022


JDK
OpenJDK 11.0.23


Operating system
centos7.9



Steps and Issues Encountered:

first conduct environmental verification,


using the flink sql client ,executing  create table and insert into table commands, successfully synchronizing data from TEST_FOR_FLINK.dbo.orders to DW.dbo.orders_dw.


Then I followed the documentation here :

Extract the following file to the corresponding directory of /flink-1.19.1:



flink-cdc-3.1.0-bin.tar.gz


Copy the following files to /flink-1.19.1/lib/:


flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.2-1.18.jar
mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar
flink-sql-connector-sqlserver-cdc-3.1.0.jar


Copy the following  file mssql-to-mssql-test01.yaml to /flink-1.19.1/pipeline/.


source:
  type: sqlserver-cdc
  hostname: x.x.x.x
  port: 1433
  username: sa
  password: xxxxxx
  database: TEST_FOR_FLINK
  tables: dbo.orders
  server-time-zone: UTC

sink:
  type: jdbc
  driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  url: jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433;databaseName=DW
  username: sa
  password: xxxxxx
  table-name: dbo.orders_dw

pipeline:
  name: Sync MSSQL Database to MSSQL
  parallelism: 2


Execute the following command:

[root@master pipeline]# flink-cdc.sh mssql-to-mssql-test01.yaml


Error Message:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find factory with identifier "sqlserver-cdc" in the classpath.

Available factory classes are:

        at org.apache.flink.cdc.composer.utils.FactoryDiscoveryUtils.getFactoryByIdentifier(FactoryDiscoveryUtils.java:62)
        at org.apache.flink.cdc.composer.flink.translator.DataSourceTranslator.translate(DataSourceTranslator.java:47)
        at org.apache.flink.cdc.composer.flink.FlinkPipelineComposer.compose(FlinkPipelineComposer.java:101)
        at org.apache.flink.cdc.cli.CliExecutor.run(CliExecutor.java:71)
        at org.apache.flink.cdc.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:71)

I hope someone can point out what I did wrong.  The official documentation does not provide an ETL example for SQL Server to SQL Server use yaml file.  If YAML files cannot be used for data transfer, where can I find documents or java project demo to use Java + Table API for data synchronization?

sqlserver-cdc pipeline connector is not supported yet, you can wait the PR https://github.com/apache/flink-cdc/pull/3445
